# jsfiddle throws an error while validating the form

Tags: jsfiddle

My form isn´t validated  I don´t know why. I tried js fiddle and now there is an error:

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa9dfd8c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0xa77d52c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_wrap', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xa9dfd8c>, 'html_name': 'js_wrap', 'html_initial_id': u'initial-id_js_wrap', 'label': u'Js wrap', 'field': <django.forms.fields.TypedChoiceField object at 0xa92e7cc>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_wrap'}"}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JeffersonSampaul/GSY83/2/

can anybody tell what mistake I am doing here???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle doesn't use the jQuery library nor the jquery.validation external library.

Here's a fixed [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/GSY83/3/).

The code is the untouched.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual",

function (value, element, param) {
    return this.optional(element) || value !== param;
},
    "Please specify a different (non-default) value");

$("#research").validate({
    rules: {
        address: {
            notEqual: "ADDRESS"
        },
        building: {
            notEqual: "BUILDING"
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function () {
        $("#research").submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank u. Kindly tell me how to use  jQuery library nor the jquery.validation external library. I am new to jsfiddle.

Comment: There's a menu to the left of the code. Also, accept this answer if it solved your problem